# What is the hex code for Nokia Blue on Windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to use NOkia blue for some of my controls for an app that I am building. I am testing the app on Nokia Lumia 800 and all the colors show differently. I am wondering if anybody can share the hex code of Nokia Blue theme in windows phone.

Comment: I am talking about the Nokia Blue theme that comes on Nokia Lumia devices.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Nokia Blue: #004C9A
```

I finally got this from XDA Forum. Credit goes to them.

Answer (score 0):

Found on [microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769545%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_DeterminingThemeBackgroundAndAccentColor) to determine accent color:

```
Color currentAccentColorHex = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];

string currentAccentColor = "";

switch (currentAccentColorHex.ToString())
{
    case "#FF1BA1E2": currentAccentColor = "blue"; break;

    case "#FFA05000": currentAccentColor = "brown"; break;

    case "#FF339933": currentAccentColor = "green"; break;

    case "#FFE671B8": currentAccentColor = "pink"; break;

    case "#FFA200FF": currentAccentColor = "purple"; break;

    case "#FFE51400": currentAccentColor = "red"; break;

    case "#FF00ABA9": currentAccentColor = "teal (viridian)"; break;

    // Lime changed to #FFA2C139 in Windows Phone OS 7.1.
    case "#FF8CBF26": 
    case "#FFA2C139": currentAccentColor = "lime"; break;

    // Magenta changed to # FFD80073 in Windows Phone OS 7.1.
    case "#FFFF0097": 
    case "#FFD80073": currentAccentColor = "magenta"; break;

    // #FFF9609 (previously orange) is named mango in Windows Phone OS 7.1.
    case "#FFF09609": currentAccentColor = "mango (orange)"; break;

    // Mobile operator or hardware manufacturer color
    default: currentAccentColor = "custom eleventh color"; break;
}
```

So blue is: `#FF1BA1E2`

If not, you can write your own quick test code:

```
Color currentAccentColorHex = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];
MessageBox.Show("#" + currentAccentColorHex.ToString("X2"));
```

Before running this code, set your theme to nokia blue.